# ¿Cómo puedo añadir a la ruta de construcción del proyecto las imágenes de la carpeta resources?

Tags: java, netbeans-11.2, excepciones

[image: ued]

Partiendo de esta imagen quisiera poder autocompletar el nombre de los recursos (que son en este caso imágenes) cuando estoy escribiendo el código en netbeans.

En Eclipse, esto se hace añadiendo la carpeta de las imágenes al build path como "Use as Source Folder" o carpeta fuente.

Una vez hecho esto, Eclipse ya me permite acceder a las imágenes autocompletando el archivo.

Actualmente estoy obteniendo una IOexception por que la carpeta de recursos no está bien adjuntada al proyecto.

¿Cómo podría importar la carpeta de imágenes para hacer "Use as Source Folder" en NetBeans?

Esta sería la línea que genera la IOException:

```
public static final HojaSprites hojaCoches = new HojaSprites(320, 320, "/img/4.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Da clic derecho sobre tu proyecto y ve al apartado de propiedades

[image: Click en properties]

2. Ahora, da clic sobre ella y te saldrá esta pantalla:

[image: Pantalla de Sources]

3. Da click en "Add folder" en la seccion de "Source Package Folders"
   Ahora te saldra lo siguiente:
   [image: Pantalla de los folders]
4. Ahora solo tienes que pulsar en el boton "Open" y por ultimo pulsar el boton "Ok".